# How to depersist a JSON object back into an object with associated methods?

Tags: javascript, json, class, persistence

So, I've got a javascript object, to which I've attached several methods via prototype.

No worries there.

Now, when I persist that object to JSON, only the actual property values are persisted. That makes perfect sense. How would you persist methods, anyway, right?

But, when I depersist the JSON object, I end up, of course, with an object that looks, property-wise, like my original object, which which no longer has any methods associated with it at all.

I understand +why+ that happens.

My question is, is there already a pattern of some sort for handling this situation?

For my own part, I have turned up a small js library called [Classy classes for JS](http://classy.pocoo.org/), which allows you to do something like this.

```
var MyClass = Class.$extend({
  __init__ : function() { alert('called'); },
  toString() : function() {
    return this.value;
  })
});
var obj = MyClass.$withData({value: 42});
alert(obj.toString());
```

This +does+ work, but I can't see a way to easily apply it to a deep hierarchy of objects.

EDIT: I wasn't very clear initially. I know that Classy (and jquery proper, as I've just been made aware) can apply data to a specific object to blend in prototyped methods, but the real question is how to do that for a deeper hierarchy of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have e.g. jQuery you can use `$.extend(obj, yourDataFromJSON);`

This will merge all data from the second object into the first one, overwriting existing values.

However, according to the [*Classy* code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/classy/blob/master/classy.js#L149) you can actually simply use `MyClass.$withData(yourDataFromJSON);` even for nested data:

```
for(var key in data) {
    var value = getOwnProperty(data, key);
    if(value !== undefined) rv[key] = value;
}
```

As you can see, everything from `data` is put into the object - no matter if it's another object (if you have nested data), an array or anything else that is not `undefined` (which doesn't even exist in JSON)

Comment: I did experiment with that, but it doesn't look any prototyped methods get added in on those subobjects, and honestly, I don't see how they could be, without some code somewhere performing that "$.extend(obj, yourDataFromJSON);" on each object as the hierarchy is depersisted. That's all ok, I suppose. I know js isn't like your traditional class oriented languages. I'm just wondering if there is a common pattern already in place for dealing with something like this.

Comment: withData: *Creates a new instance of the class by bypassing the constructor and assigning the attributes from the given object. This is useful if you want to attach methods to an object recieved from a JSON object* - so the object *does* have your class' methods.

Comment: Yep, the Withdata is probably the best way to go. I've run into some issues with Classy, JQMobile and Knockout, though, so the JQ extend seems to work consistently with all those libraries.